# How can i call a document in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

i have some trouble to understand the concept of mongodb. Why i can not load a document by its ID?

```
    # Start Client and mongostuff
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client.NAMEOFDATABASE
    a_collection = gridfs.GridFS(db, collection="a_collection")
    b_collection = db.b_collection

    # This works !!!
    a_collection.find_one({"_id": ObjectId("552990a75ce9fd691c2fe412")})

    # Why not this ?????????
    id = b_collection.find({"Content": "A"}).distinct("_id_IMAGE")
    a_collection.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})
```

Why i do this: I want to save text and some images in mongodb. So i save the image and then save the text with the img_ids. Then i plan to call the text and with the IDs in the text the images i stored.

```
    outputdata = a_collection.get(_id_IMAGE).read()
    # create an output file and store the image in the output file
    outfilename = "image_from_mongodb.jpg" 
    output= open(outfilename,"w")
    output.write(outputdata)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure if it's your only problem, but [`distinct`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.distinct) returns a list, not a single value.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was that i have to iterate over the results to get the ID:  for result in a_collection.find():
    media_id = result['IMAGE_ID']

Comment: @SheldonCooper: Try `db.collection.distinct("IMAGE_ID")`